# What affects does changing the column-order of a table in a database have on the server-memory?

Tags: sql-server, database

I just started my new job and after looking at the DBM I was shocked. Its a huge mess.

Now first thing I wanted to do is get some consistency in the order of table columns. We publish new database versions over a .dacpac. My co-worker told me that changing the order of a column would force MSSQL to create a temporary table which stores all the data. MSSQL then creates a new table and inserts all the data into that table.

So lets say my server only runs 2GB of RAM and has 500MB storage left on the harddrive. The whole database weights 20GB. Is it possible that changing the order of columns will cause trouble (memory related)? Is the statement of my co-worker correct?

I couldnt find any good source for my question.
Thanks!

Comment: [Does the order of columns in a table's definition matter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18719/6381) on DBA.

Comment: you can go one table by one. try to insert one tables data into temporary table and if operation doesn't crash - it means you are good.

Comment: one risk that could happen, is that a program somewhere may have used a 'select * From', then accessed columns by its ordinal (you can do this in .net).  If the underlying columns change order, then that sort of code could break.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT "go one table by one".

You should leave your tables as they are, if you don't like the order of columns of some table just create a `view` reordering your columns as you want.

Not only changing order of columns will cause your tables to be recreated, all the `indexes` will be recreated, you'll get problems with `FK` constraints.

And after all, you'll gain absolutely nothig but do damage only. You'll waste server resources, make your tables temporarily inaccessible and the columns will not be stored as you defind anyway, internally they will be stored in "var-fix" format (divided into fixed-length and variable-length)

Comment: To add to this - if the schema is a "mess", then the code using it is also likely a mess. Changing the schema will almost certainly cause errors downstream. For one, you will quickly find usages of "select * from table"